# Django auth context processor: not to query for user for each request

Tags: django, performance, authentication

I enabled django auth middleware, so now I have a user variable in my request context. 
In this case for each page request user object is queried from the database. Is it possible to set up this middleware to use a cached user object (for example, that was placed by me in the session)?
User objects are not updated frequently, so I don't need to have an extra DB query for each page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can do this, and I think that it's also a good idea :)

I did this with a custom auth backend in which the get_user method tries to retrieve the user from cache (and then from db in case of cache miss).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store the user in the session.

The only thing you have look out for is that if you make changes to that user object, that users who are logged into your system while you push an update might not have that change (ie a property you added).

Just make sure you make your middleware check the object, or write some code somewhere that can. This might be something you only drop in for a release of a user change, and then pull out after the release. (if you're using the django auth user, you prolly wont be changing it at all)